# Reachability.mのreachabilityWithAddressはそのまま使っていて良い？

Tags: ios

IPv6の対応方法がよくわからなくて困っています。
Apple提供のReachability.mがありますが、このなかでzeroAddressでReachabilityRefを取りに行っているところがあります。
このメソッドはそのまま使用していていいのでしょうか?
IPv6のアドレスに解決された場合、`sockaddr_in` などの変数がオーバーフローするのでは、と思っています。

```
+ (instancetype)reachabilityWithAddress:(const struct sockaddr_in *)hostAddress
{
  SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const struct sockaddr *)hostAddress);

  MVReachability* returnValue = NULL;

  if (reachability != NULL)
  {
    returnValue = [[self alloc] init];
    if (returnValue != NULL)
    {
      returnValue->_reachabilityRef = reachability;
      returnValue->_alwaysReturnLocalWiFiStatus = NO;
    }
  }
  return returnValue;
}



+ (instancetype)reachabilityForInternetConnection
{
  struct sockaddr_in zeroAddress;
  bzero(&zeroAddress, sizeof(zeroAddress));
  zeroAddress.sin_len = sizeof(zeroAddress);
  zeroAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;

  return [self reachabilityWithAddress:&zeroAddress];
}
```

Comment: 'IPv6 only Internet Sharing' の機能をつかって確認したところ、IPv6でも`_reachabilityRef` は常に0.0.0.0 のアドレスを持っているようでした。ただこれだけではIPv6でもデフォルトルートを表していることになるのかよくわからず、不安が残る状態。。

Comment: El Capitanの'IPv6 only Internet Sharing' の機能を使って動作確認したときは問題なく動作したので、動作は問題なさそうです。ロジックだけ見たときに、どうして問題ないのかが理解できていないです。

Comment: 具体的にどの処理（or どの行）で変数がオーバーフローすると考えておられますか？